# Access denied error while creating sub directory inside the directory

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, active-directory

I am facing one problem while creating the subdirectory inside a directory.The error message shown is **'Access to the path 'tempimages' is denied.**'

I have given full access permission to some of the user accounts in the drive where directory is to be created via application.

Now in the global.asax i have registered one method which will allow the above user accounts to create a directory.I am able to create parent directory after assigning the access rule for the user accounts.
But when i try to create the subdirectory inside that directory using the same access rules.I get the above error.

```
        string useraccountForDirectoryCreate = System.Environment.UserDomainName;
        dacl.AddAccessRule(new System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemAccessRule(useraccountForDirectoryCreate,
        System.Security.AccessControl.FileSystemRights.FullControl,
                System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit |
                System.Security.AccessControl.InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
                System.Security.AccessControl.PropagationFlags.None,
                System.Security.AccessControl.AccessControlType.Allow));
        Directory.CreateDirectory(imageDirectory, dacl);


        Directory.CreateDirectory(tempImageDirectory, dacl);
        DirectoryInfo obj = new DirectoryInfo(imageDirectory);
        obj.CreateSubdirectory(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["networkStoragePathTemp"].ToString(), dacl);//Access to the path 'tempimages' is denied
```

I did some search for the above case but to no success,
Please help,
Thanks S.

Answer (score 0):

**The Error message clearly saying this is happening due to the Permission problem while creating the Sub directory in the Root Directory.**

If you are using IIS 7.5, try granting the group:  IIS_IUSRS access, if the above uses a built in account.